# Colors in Mac PowerPoint not exactly as specified

Tags: macos, mac, colors, microsoft-powerpoint

(crossposting from https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21918/colors-in-mac-powerpoint-not-exactly-as-specified)

In Mac PowerPoint, I tried setting the fill color of a rectangle and the text color of text to the same value, but they appear slightly different (see image below). Overlaying them here just to show its not an optical illusion, I'd have expected the text to be invisible above the box.

For instance, here I set them both to RGB(75,172,98).  But they are clearly different.
Using Mac OS X Digital Color meter, in PowerPoint:

- the fill is RGB(94,186,207) and
- the text is RGB(80,172,96).

Neither have transparency, shadows, or anything else I can think of.  What might I be doing wrong?  ju

[image: Should be the same color but not]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac PowerPoint (or the Mac OS color manglement system) treats text differently from other shapes.  That's why you're seeing this.  However if you choose Generic RGB profile, the problem goes away.

There's more about it on the PowerPoint FAQ site that I keep up:

Colors appear different on Mac vs PC PowerPoint
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ01173-Colors-appear-different-on-Mac-vs-PC-PowerPoint.htm

Comment: This was exactly it!  Presumably a color theorist had tried to address the optical illusion of text appearing different even when exactly the same.  Or their tech support people got tired of hearing about text disappearing.

Comment: ;-)  AKA "It doesn't make much sense to me either".  But that's what they did.  Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

Can you assign colors using CMYK, PMS, HSL or HEX values instead of RGB?

Also, make sure you clear all text attributes. I've seen 3D effects (depth, contour, surface, etc.) cause color shifts in text that I thought was "plain".

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that when inputting RGB values into software (Excel, PowerPoint, InDesign, etc.) the colours do not render correctly. According to the DigitalColor Meter they come out as something other than the input values. To fix this use sRGB values, and they will render correctly. At least that is what worked for me. Generic RGB and Adobe RGB values did not work with my iMac. sRGB values work perfectly. Playing with the display colour settings did not help, so I put it back on the original "iMac" setting.